# Придаточное перед тире: нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, придаточное-предложение

> Если же нет времени разбираться, как глобальные изменения влияют на
>   нас(,) – не беда.

Вот я всё время путаю. Теоретически это придаточное предложение, значит запятая нужна перед тире. Но что-то я сомневаюсь. Обязательна ли тут запятая?

С другой стороны, бывает синонимия тире и запятой, где запятая полностью поглощается тире. В идеале, конечно, я бы вообще сделала парцелляцию вроде "Нет времени разбираться, как глобальные изменения влияют на нас? Не беда!", но автор не я, я не хочу так перестраивать текст. Однако без парцелляции что-то есть во всей фразе корявое, но я не понимаю, что не так.

В общем-то, основной вопрос про запятую, а насчёт парцелляции - опционально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая обязательна.
Принцип простой: она ставится перед словом ЭТО или если оно подставляется по смыслу:
*Если же нет времени разбираться, как глобальные изменения влияют на нас, – (это) не беда.

Самое лучшее, что он мог сделать, — (это) вовремя уйти.

Кто виноват из них, кто прав, — (об этом) судить не нам.

Что это был за случай, в котором было столько неясного, — (этого) он припомнить не мог.

Единственное, что мне здесь нравится, — это старый тенистый парк.*

Comment: ...подставляется по смыслу? Розенталь сказал? Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку.

Comment: Эта закономерность прослеживается во всех его примерах, где есть определение понятия. Не говорил, но это очевидно. Про запятую перед словом ЭТО говорил. Если ЭТО изымаем, запятую убирать? Нет, конечно. Это обратный эффект.

Answer (score 2):

**Из правил** Розенталя можно сделать вывод, что запятая нужна, но обратим внимание на предложение, приведенное в качестве примера:

*Его походка была небрежна и ленива, но я заметил, что он не размахивал руками, — первый признак некоторой скрытности характера* (Л.) — запятая закрывает придаточную часть сложноподчиненного предложения, тире поставлено перед своеобразным приложением к предшествующим словам, имеет **присоединительный** оттенок.

Зачем Розенталь упоминает **про присоединительный характер** второй части предложения?

Интонационно желательно различать **два тире**: разделительное и присоединительное, потому что разделительная интонация – восходяще-нисходящая, а присоединительная – нисходяще-нисходящая.

*Если же нет времени разбираться, **как глобальные изменения влияют на нас** – не беда.*

В этом предложении со значением "условие – следствие" тире именно разделительное, запятая помешает выразить взаимообусловленность. Я полагаю, что запятая здесь не нужна.

Как это обосновать? Правилами не получится, только примерами из хорошей современной литературы.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Хотя один пример у Розенталя всё-таки есть, можно сослаться на него: *Пишут, **чтобы мы обязательно приезжали** — будут встречать;*

Но здесь присоединительное тире

Розенталь, п. 7:  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151

Comment: У Розенталя есть ещё один пример: "*Я отвечал, что меня беспокоят мухи, — и мы оба замолчали* (Л.) — запятая закрывает придаточную часть, тире поставлено перед частью предложения, выражающей следствие."

Comment: Следствие, может, и есть, да нет взаимообусловленности. Примеры из пословиц со значением ЕСЛИ: Сделал дело — гуляй смело. Любишь кататься — люби и саночки возить.

Comment: @Sharon, почему нельзя обосновать правилами?Вот ссылка.  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142

Comment: А где там такой пример, чтобы придаточное не закрывалось запятой перед тире?

Comment: Тире можно объяснить тем, что вторая часть является изъяснительным придаточным и стоит впереди главного.

Comment: Вот именно, там нет запятой. Только тире.

Comment: Вы об этом предложении :Если же нет времени разбираться, как глобальные изменения влияют на нас(,) – не беда. Здесь основная часть: Если нет времени  – не беда. Тире в этом СПП ставится как неосновной знак, обозначает паузу. Но придаточное условия дополнительно распространено изъяснительным придаточным. Его надо закрывать запятой?